# Flutter: Unable to locate gradlew script .bat

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, gradlew

Somebody help me to fix this error, after downloading flutter sdk, android studio. I setup env. variables and all, after that my first project is running normally but when i created another projects they are not running all are showing the same error **Unable to locate gradlew script. Please check that D:\Projects\Intro2\android\gradlew.bat exists or that D:\Projects\Intro2\android can be read**
and then showing **Exited (sigterm)**

What is this problem?
Did i have to reinstall all again?

Comment: Did you make aure that `gradlew.bat` exists in the specified location?

Comment: @mousetail yes gradlew file exists in the specified location. i created 4 projects from now   all showing same problem :-/